# Codeigniter Query Doesnot Give Proper Answer

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have a web project that is under development. I want to select data from database by **group** having a **condition**. But the problem is CodeIgniter doesn't give me the actually expected result. For reference, I am sharing code below.

**First query**

```
$this->db->select('serial, wardno, COUNT(serial) as total');
    $this->db->where('status','active');
    $this->db->group_by('wardno');
    $data['wards'] = $this->db->get('certi_charter_inherit')->result_object();
```

First query give doesnot give me the targated result. It generates result.

```
[wards] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [serial] => 6
                [wardno] => 2
                [total] => 2
            )

    )
```

This is not my expectation. But If I use another direct query then it works clearly.

**Second Query**

```
$data['wards'] = $this->db->query("SELECT serial, wardno, COUNT(serial) as 'total' from certi_trade WHERE status='active' GROUP by wardno")->result_object();

[wards] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [serial] => 3
                    [wardno] => 1
                    [total] => 2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [serial] => 6
                    [wardno] => 2
                    [total] => 1
                )

        )
```

The second query generates the result like below. And it is correct. I have tested my **phpmyadmin console**. So I confused which one should be used. I like the first one.

Any help is highly appriciated.

Comment: You are selecting from two different tables, so the result is not unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

Please change your **table name** here as per your **second query** :
$data['wards'] = $this->db->get('certi_trade')->result_object();